# Error: libcrypto.so.1.1: could not open while try run WPS-Office on Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)

Tags: wps-office, 22.04

---

### Introduction

Hello I am user Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)

In the last version ubuntu i used (Ubuntu 21.10). Previously I could run wps-office from shortcut or terminal. However after I upgraded my ubuntu to version 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) and upgraded my kernel to Linux version `5.17.3-051703-generic`. I can't run my wps, and when I run it in terminal it doesn't give output anything like a program that has stopped. But when I run it with command `sudo wps` it running well.

Some of the tests I have tried are running the wps binary files directly from the `/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6` directory.

---

### Run without sudo

If I try to run wps-office use command `$ ./wps` it will give the output like:

```
sann@sann-x86-64:/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6$ ./wps
dlopen /opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/libkprometheus.so failed , error: libcrypto.so.1.1: could not open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

### Run with sudo

But if I try to run wps-office use command `$ sudo ./wps` the applications is running well.

---

### The Question

How to run my wps-office without root access like usual, because it will give output `error: libcrypto.so.1.1: could not open` from binary files?

By the way my specifications:

```
$ hostnamectl
       Icon name: computer-laptop
         Chassis: laptop
      Machine ID: bf04614f92c14cfc852e40a21044494b
         Boot ID: 9e24b1c62abb423dab886b65d3ecc9ed
Operating System: Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish (development branch)
          Kernel: Linux 5.17.3-051703-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Acer
  Hardware Model: One Z1402

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish (development branch)
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I'm very grateful for the help (:

Comment: Hello. 22.04 does not exist yet. Until it does it is off topic on this site. It is beta right now and that is off topic.

Comment: Thanks for the response, maybe I should just wait until this topic gets hot and use `sudo wps` instead of `wps` for while time.

Comment: It worked directly for me... The installer must have been updated. Download version `wps-office_11.1.0.11664.XA_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same problem also found on Xubuntu 22.04, wps office only run with sudo.

**Solved :**
Manual install libssl-1.1 package, it's works and wps office can running without sudo again.

```
wget https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb

dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the wps now works without root :D

Comment: Thanks. This works!

Comment: There is a new version of the lib that replaced the old one. Use 
`wget https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb` and `dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb`

Comment: Thanks very much @Chris for the update. Works like a charm.

Comment: WPS Pdf was crashing. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I've got the same issue here. It looks it's all about permission of two files `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` under folder `/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6`. Changing their permission to **755** will work.

Comment: this is an even better answer because it doesn't require any additional install

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. WPS Office 11 wasn't starting in Ubuntu 22.04, but without any errors in the terminal. And it was starting just fine when using `sudo wps`.

**Solution** the solved my problem:

1. Download the .rpm package and convert it with alien to .deb

   sudo alien wps-office-11.1.0.10976.XA-1.x86_64.rpm
2. install the new .deb package

   sudo apt install ./wps-office-11.1.0.10976.XA-1.x86_64.deb

Comment: Alien is unmaintained, and possibly unsafe (can introduce system-breaking issues), this is not recommanded