# WPS office no longer works on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, wps-office

https://www.wps.com/office/linux/

this used to run fine, now nothing happens when I run WPS office.

Comment: Do you have a `libcrypto.so.1.1` error if you run it from terminal? If yes, probably you should read here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403055/error-libcrypto-so-1-1-could-not-open-while-try-run-wps-office-on-ubuntu-22-04/1405329#1405329

Comment: hey thanks! what about this solution? worked for me. seems more straightforward. https://askubuntu.com/a/1405172/307184

Comment: Yeah, good that you found, among the different answers, the one that best solves your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: libcrypto.so.1.1: could not open while try run WPS-Office on Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403055/error-libcrypto-so-1-1-could-not-open-while-try-run-wps-office-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: This solved the issue for me. https://askubuntu.com/a/1403463

Comment: It worked directly for me... The installer must have been updated. Download version `wps-office_11.1.0.11664.XA_amd64.deb` on June 28, 2022

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://www.wps.com/download/ now, it works well for me.
My system is ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1342087)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).